# Partial View Search Results load to another page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, search, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have an asp.net mvc project which has a typical search function. I have my main view then when the user clicks an option it loads the partial view on the same view however when I do search inside the partial view it loads the results to another page.

Here's the code of my main view:

```
<section class="content" id="partialview">
            <!-- Main row -->
            <div class="row">
                <a href="#" id="option1">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 wrapper">
                        <center><div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"><img src="~/Images/icon.png" class="icons" /></div></center>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"><div class="text">Option1</div></div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </section>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("option1").onclick = function () { ViewResults() };
function ViewResults() {
    $("#partialview").load("@Url.Action("ActionName", "Controller")");
}
</script>
```

And here's the controller that loads the partial view:

```
public ActionResult ActionName(DateTime? datefrom, DateTime? dateto)
    {
        Model rmodel = new Model();
        string path = Server.MapPath("~/Files/");
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);


        if (datefrom != null && dateto != null)
        {
            rmodel = dir.GetFiles("*.pdf*").Where(a => a.CreationTime >= datefrom && a.CreationTime <= dateto);
        }
        else
        { 
            rmodel.PDFFile = dir.GetFiles("*.pdf*")
        }

        return View(rmodel);
    }
```

Any idea ? Thanks.

**EDIT**

Here's the partial view:

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "Controller", FormMethod.Get))
        {
          <div class="form-inline">
          <div class="form-group">
              @Html.TextBox("datefrom", null, new { @placeholder = "Date         
                         From", @class = "form-control", @id = "DateFrom" })
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
             @Html.TextBox("dateto", null, new { @placeholder = "Date To",   
                         @class = "form-control", @id = "DateTo" })
          </div>
       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" value="Filter" />
          </div>
       }
```

The code for the search/filter is in the controller already.

Comment: What is the partial view that your loading when you click the element with `id="option1"`? and what is the code associated with the 'search'?

Comment: See my edit. Thanks.

Comment: Its a form that makes a GET, so of course it will redirect to another page. Are you wanting to display the results of the search on the same page? In which case you need to use ajax.

Comment: No it would need to be `Ajax.BeginForm()`, but I recommend that you just use the jQuery ajax methods instead (`$.ajax()` or `$.get()` or `.load()`)

Comment: What would be the difference ?

Comment: But in any case, you need to break this into 2 partials. If you do not want the form initially, then your existing option click should load the form and then handling the form should return the results (no point adding the form again)

Comment: Same result. But the jQuery methods give far more flexibility and control, and mean you do not need the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script (and the `Ajax` methods are not even supported in the latest version of MVC)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ActionName", "ActionName", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "tagId"}))`
This will dump the html returned from the server in the tagId (which is the id of the container of the rendred html). You will not need to use any extra script. 
 Or you can also use jquery function in this case you will not need the html helper and you will use something like this in your script

```
 var values = {
                    datefrom: $('#DateFrom').val(),
                    dateto: $('#DateTo').val(),
                };

                $.ajax({
                    url: "Controller/Action",
                    type: "get",
                    data: values,
                    success: function (html) {
                        $("#tagId").html(html); 
                    }
                });
```